# Implementing Numpy Like Access to Elements in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, getter, setter

I implemented a Matrix class. I want to code some Linear Algebra concepts by using it. Sometimes I need to access a row/column vector of the matrix or set a vector to any column/row of the matrix. Like we do in Numpy as below:

```
        col_vec = A[:,2]
        A[1,:] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        A[:,2] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I thought that I can overload [] operator and pass a string in it like below:

```
        A[":,2"]
```

Is there any way to do this without passing string? Also I want to assign a vector to the specified row or column of the matrix.

Comment: If this not some sort of practice/exercise, then I highly suggest looking at linear algebra libraries. E.g. [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) is extremely high performant, quite easy to use and very well known.

Comment: It *may* be possible with some clever use of comma operator overloading (if you can allow to use a different symbol instead of `:`, maybe `_` or `$`) and multiple proxy classes, but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort. Python has built-in support for slicing, C++ has not.

Comment: It's just for fun and exercise. I'm learning Linear Algebra and in parallel I want to improve my C++ skills. So it seems it doesn't deserve the effort, I'll just  implement another functions for these purposes. Thanks.